# Verificar se um usuário está seguindo o outro, utilizando a API do SC (sound cloud) em Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma página WEB, onde essa página vai estar utilizando a [API SDK do SC](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks). 
O que acontece, é que não estou conseguindo utilizar a função que verificar se um usuário segue o outro.
No caso, o usuário iria logar na pagina e uma função iria verificar se esse usuário que está logado, se está seguindo o usuário dono da pagina...

Nesse caso eu fiz de um jeito, porém é limitado pelo SC.

```
$("#connect").live("click", function(){
var follo = 400;
SC.get("/users/"+ idUser +"/followings",{
            limit: follo
        },function (followings) {

        for (var i = 0; i < followings.length; i++){
             var id = followings[i].id;
             if(id == idUser){
               alert('True');
               break;
        };
  };
});
```

Desse jeito até funciona como eu quero, eu pego a lista de todas as pessoas que o usuário segue e verifico se o dono da página está nessa lista, porém... se eu não definir um limite, o limite default é de 50 usuário, e se eu definir um limite, posso expandir até no MAXIMO 200 usuário, mesmo que o limite seja 400 como no exemplo a cima, porém tem usuários que seguem bem mais usuários.
No link que eu passei a cima, existe um exemplo que acho que resolveria meu caso, porém não achei um jeito certo de utilizar:

```
/users/{id}/followings/{id} a user who is followed by the user.
```